# SyntaxError: Unexpected token import at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I got the below error

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/b
  uild/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/containers/login/login.container.js:7:48)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/containers/routes.js:18:243)
```

trying hard to fix it.

Comment: there are bunch of topics by request [jest token import](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jest+token+import). it'd be faster to you check them.